# cout printing garbage when string is concatenated with array value

Tags: c++, cout

Here is my very basic C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

char values[] = {'y'};

int main() {
    std::cout << "x" + values[0];
}
```

My expected output would just be `xy`, but instead I am just getting random text/symbols

Comment: This isn't how to do string concatenation in C++. Use `std::string("x")` instead of `"x"`.

Comment: Like this: `std::cout << std::string("x") + values[0];`?

Comment: That will work, so will `std::cout << "x" << values[0];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to do:

```
std::cout << "x" << values[0];
```

Otherwise, you are taking `"x"` (which decays into a pointer to the 1st element of a const array that holds the characters {`'x'`, `'\0'`} in memory), and adding `'y'` (which has the numeric value 121 when converted to an `int`) to that pointer.

Adding an integer  to a pointer changes what it points to. You are reading memory that is 121 bytes beyond the `'x'` character in memory, so you are going to be reading random bytes, or causing an Access Violation.

Comment: Thanks, that makes much more sense. I know this might be a whole separate question, but if I had a lot of values that need to be concatenated, would there be a better way, or is spamming `<<` the only option?

Comment: << is the most efficient. It will output to the stream one by one. If you concatenate a bunch of things then you are copying them around in memory, reallocating buffers, just to send them all to the stream anyway